# Binding nested objects in SPRING MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to SPRING MVC. I am not getting all the details of employee which contains phone and address object as well. Actually, those object are not being binded with employee.

Follow the code:

//(Controller)

EmployeeController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController {
@Autowired  
EmployeeService employeeService;  
@RequestMapping("/employee")  
public ModelAndView registerEmployeer(@ModelAttribute Employee employee) {  
Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<>();
modelMap.put("employee", new Employee());
return new ModelAndView("employee", modelMap);
}
@RequestMapping("/add")    
public String addemployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee) {
employeeService.save(employee);
return "result";
}
@ModelAttribute("phoneTypeList")
public Map<String,String> populatePhoneTypeList() 
{
return Phone.getPhoneTypes();
}
@ModelAttribute("addressTypeList")
public Map<String,String> populateAddressTypeList() 
{
return Address.getAddressTypes();
}
}
```

//Form which takes employee details
employee.jsp

```
<h2>Employee Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="employee/add"
modelAttribute="employee">
<table>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="ssn">SSN</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="ssn" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="firstname">First Name</form:label>           </td>
<td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="lastname">Last Name</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="dob">Date of Birth</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="dob" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="emailid">Email</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="emailid" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone Type:</td>
<td><form:select path="phoneList[0].phonetype" multiple="false">
<form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
<form:options items="${phoneTypeList}" />
</form:select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="phoneList[0].phoneno">Phone</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="phoneList[0].phoneno" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address Type:</td>
<td><form:select path="addressList[0].addresstype"
multiple="false">
<form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
<form:options items="${addressTypeList}" />
</form:select></td>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="addressList[0].street">Street</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="addressList[0].street" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="addressList[0].city">City</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="addressList[0].city" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="addressList[0].state">State</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="addressList[0].state" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="addressList[0].zip">Zip</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="addressList[0].zip" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="addressList[0].country">Country</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="addressList[0].country" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"
value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

//Result after submitting form
result.jsp

```
<h2>Submitted Employee Information</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>SSN</td>
<td>${employee.ssn}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>${employee.firstname}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>${employee.lastname}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date of Birth</td>
<td>${employee.dob}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>${employee.emailid}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone Type</td>
<td>${employee.phoneList[0].phonetype}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>${phoneList[0].phoneno}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address Type</td>
<td>${addressList.addressTypeList}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Street</td>
<td>${addressList.street}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City</td>
<td>${addressList.city}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State</td>
<td>${addressList.state}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zip</td>
<td>${addressList.zip}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td>${addressList.country}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

//my employee bean looks like this
employee.java

```
public class Employee {
private List<Phone> phoneList = new ArrayList<Phone>();
private List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<Address>();
private long ssn;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String dob;
private String emailid;
public long getSsn() {
return ssn;
}
public void setSsn(long ssn) {
this.ssn = ssn;
}
public String getFirstname() {
return firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
return lastname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
this.lastname = lastname;
}
public String getDob() {
return dob;
}
public void setDob(String dob) {
this.dob = dob;
}
public String getEmailid() {
return emailid;
}
public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
this.emailid = emailid;
}
public void addPhone(Phone ph) {
phoneList.add(ph);
}
public void addAddress(Address ad) {
addressList.add(ad);
}
public void setPhoneList(List<Phone> phoneList) {
this.phoneList = phoneList;
}
public List<Phone> getPhoneList() {
return phoneList;
}
public List<Address> getAddressList() {
return addressList;
}
public void setAddressList(List<Address> adList) {
this.addressList = adList;
}
}
```

I can get only those details of employee like ssn, first name, last name etc but not phone type, phone no, address details which are the field of another objects. My assumption is the binding is not working here. Any idea?

Comment: Output I got as:                                        
SSN 213209567 
First Name abc 
Last Name def 
Date of Birth 2-3-87 
Email abc@cde.com 
Phone Type  
Phone  
Address Type  
Street  
City  
State  
Zip  
Country

Comment: can i see employee bean, it looks like mapping issue .

Comment: @PankajSharma: Now, You can see employee bean as well

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, solved by removing this line:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

before the `@ElementCollection` that was not copied.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "employee" as prefix & index in list elements when reading them.

```
<tr>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>${employee.phoneList[0].phoneno}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address Type</td>
<td>${employee.addressList[0].addressTypeList}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Street</td>
<td>${employee.addressList[0].street}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City</td>
<td>${employee.addressList[0].city}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State</td>
<td>${employee.addressList[0].state}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zip</td>
<td>${employee.addressList[0].zip}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td>${employee.addressList[0].country}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That Did not work and I am still stuck in same place